# javascript foreach var weird ptr

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, scope

I'm stuck with javascript forEach func.
Here's some piece of code:

```js
const PPPP =
    {
        'azerty': 0,
      'qwerty': []
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
      var k = [];
      var z = [0, 1, 2, 3];
      
      var m = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
      
      z.forEach(function(v) {
        
        var p = Object.assign({}, PPPP);
        
        $('#debug').append(v.toString()+', ');
        p.azerty = v;
        
        m.forEach(function(v) {
          
          p.qwerty.push(v);
          
        });
        
        k.push(p);
        
      });
      
      $('#res').html('Final: '+JSON.stringify(k));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="debug"></div>
    <div id="res"></div>
```

Expected: 
Final: 0, 1, 2, 3,
Final: [{"azerty":0,"qwerty":["a","b","c"]},{"azerty":1,"qwerty":["a","b","c"]},{"azerty":2,"qwerty":["a","b","c"]},{"azerty":3,"qwerty":["a","b","c"]}]

Could anyone propose an alternative to fix this ?
Thank you!

Edit #1: Fixed with manual copy assignment. But doesn't work with forEach in forEach for unknown reason.

Comment: You should explain what you expect this code to do and what happens instead.

Comment: How about explain?

Comment: Status update. Solution doesn't work anymore with forEach in forEach.

Comment: Solved, but still weird.. I had to dispose of the inner forEach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The p object has same reference within the loop. You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create a new object based on `PPPP`

```js
const PPPP =
{
    'azerty': 0
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  var k = [];
  var z = [0, 1, 2, 3];
  
  z.forEach(function(v) {
    
    var p = Object.assign({},PPPP);
    
    $('#debug').append(v.toString()+', ');
    p.azerty = v;
    k.push(p);
    
  });
  
  $('#res').html('Final: '+JSON.stringify(k));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="debug"></div>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: Good alternative too. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the same object in the loop. You could move the object inside of the callback and use a new object for every loop.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var k = [];
  var z = [0, 1, 2, 3];
  
  z.forEach(function(v) {
    const PPPP = { 'azerty': 0 }; // move to this place
    
    var p = PPPP;
    
    $('#debug').append(v.toString()+', ');
    p.azerty = v;
    k.push(p);
    
  });
  
  $('#res').html('Final: '+JSON.stringify(k));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="debug"></div>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: Thank ! Lot of pain avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You shold define `var p` as blank object like below::

```
var p = {};
```

rest of your code should remain same. That's it.